# How to access file from bundle in unit tests

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing, bundle

I'm doing Unit tests and I'm trying to get a file from `bundle`, but on line `let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: SecCertificate)` I get the error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'SecCertificate.Type.Type' to expected argument type 'AnyClass' (aka 'AnyObject.Type')

```
enum CertificatesMock: CertificatesType {

    case myWebUrl

    var host: [String] {

        switch self {
        case .myWebUrl:
            return ["https://my.web.url/"]
        }
    }

    var certificates: SecCertificate {

        switch self {
        case .myWebUrl:

            let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: SecCertificate))
            return CertificatesMock.certificate(filename: "myWebUrl", bundle: bundle)
        }
    }

    private static func certificate(filename: String, bundle: Bundle) -> SecCertificate {

        if let filePath = bundle.path(forResource: filename, ofType: "cer") {

            do {

                let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath))
                let certificate = SecCertificateCreateWithData(nil, data as CFData)!

                return certificate

            } catch {

                fatalError(CertificatesError.noCertificateFound.description + ": " + filename)
            }

        } else {

            fatalError(CertificatesError.noCertificateFound.description + ": " + filename)
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I have that file in my `UnitTests` target but don't know how to access it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to access the bundle from an enum, but according to your error it can be only from an `AnyClass` object.

> Cannot convert value of type 'CertificatesMock.Type' to expected
> argument type 'AnyClass' (aka 'AnyObject.Type')

An enum(In your case CertificatesMock) won't conform to `AnyClass`, therefore the error. One workaround is to define a class with a property of bundle, and retrieve it from there. It is valid in this case because `BundleClass` conforms to `AnyClass`

```
class BundleClass {
    var bundle: Bundle {
        return Bundle(for: type(of: self))
    }
}

// To use it
let bundle = BundleClass().bundle()
```

One can wonder if the bundle can be a static member, as it is not really efficient to initialise a new member every time we need the bundle, but it would be invalid too. Again the self would be a `BundleClass.Type` not `AnyClass`.

**Invalid!**

```
class BundleClass {
    static var bundle: Bundle {
        return Bundle(for: type(of: self))
    }
}
```

> Cannot convert value of type 'BundleClass.Type.Type' to expected
> argument type 'AnyClass' (aka 'AnyObject.Type')

As a workaround for that you can declare a class inside your enum and using a static member you use your created class to access the bundle:

```
enum CertificatesMock1 {
    class BundleClass {}
    static var fooBundle: Bundle { return Bundle(for: CertificatesMock1.BundleClass.self) }
}
```

Comment: I get this error: `Cannot convert value of type 'CertificatesMock.Type' to expected argument type 'AnyClass' (aka 'AnyObject.Type')`

Comment: Did you try to use the **let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))** ?

Comment: @bruno were you able to solve your problem with the solution ?

Comment: I got the error I posted in the comment above, bundle only seems to work if used in a class not enum.